# PowerShell: String expansion in command mode

Tags: powershell

What are the rules of string expansion in command mode? If on cmd.exe, I would write this:

```
c:\asdoc.exe -doc-sources+=src
```

I need to convert this to a string where the actual source path ("src") is computed so somewhere above this line, `$sourcePath = "src"` is executed. Now I need to transform that cmd.exe command to PowerShell command. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
& c:\asdoc.exe -doc-sources+=$sourcePath    # does NOT work
& c:\asdoc.exe -doc-sources+="$sourcePath"  # does NOT work
& c:\asdoc.exe -doc-sources+=($sourcePath)  # does NOT work
```

I used the [EchoArgs](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2010/01/26/debugging-executing-program-from-powershell-using-echoargs-exe.aspx) utility and it gives me these results:

```
Arg 0 is <-doc-sources+=$sourcePath> # case 1

Arg 0 is <-doc-sources+=$sourcePath> # case 2

Arg 0 is <-doc-sources+=>            # case 3
Arg 1 is <src path>
```

How do I make the string expand "correctly" in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you properly you want everything expanded and as a single argument. Try to "collect" the argument with quotes.

```
PS > $sourcepath = "src"

PS > & EchoArgs.exe "-doc-sources+=$($sourcePath)"
Arg 0 is <-doc-sources+=src>
```

So try this:

```
& c:\asdoc.exe "-doc-sources+=$($sourcePath)"
```

The example below will also works AS LONG as you want to expand a variable an not a property inside a variable (ex  `$myobject.sourcepath`)

```
& c:\asdoc.exe "-doc-sources+=$sourcePath"
```